# Prove the manifold of SU(2)/U(1) is the 2-sphere.

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, group-isomorphism

I want to demonstrate that the manifold of $SU(2)/U(1)$ is a 2-sphere.
In a text-book I've found this way of solution, where there are some unclear points.

Let to be $g= a\mathbb{1} + i b_j\sigma_j$ the generic element of $SU(2)$ (with $b_j\sigma_j$ I mean a sum over $j=1,2,3$), with $a^2+b_jb^j=1$.
Now, let define a subgroup $U(1)$ of $SU(2)$ by the generic element on $\sigma_3$-direction $h=a\mathbb{1} + ix_3\sigma_3 \in U(1)$ **(why is the coefficient of $\mathbb{1}$ the same in the two cases?)** with $a^2+x_3^2=1$.
Now, we write $b_j = x_3\xi_j$ **(why?)** and the condition about the determinant returns $\xi_j\xi^j = 1$ that is the 2-sphere.

I don't understand why we don't calculate the left coset $gU(1)$ and how to deduce the isomorphism with the 2-sphere...

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed not a valid demonstration, since substituting $b_j=x_3\xi_j$ is not well-defined when $x_3=0$.

Comment: Thanks Jesper. What's the correct demonstration ?

Comment: This is the Hopf fibration, see for example the [explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration#Geometric_interpretation_using_rotations) in Wikipedia.